# Error in angular2 spa (OverlayState is not a constructor )

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-material2

I have a page with `MdDialog` and `MdSnakBar` on the same page. Showing `MdSnackBar` on this page gives an error:

```
OverlayState is not a constructor at MdSnackBar._createOverlay

Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__angular_cdk_overlay__.OverlayState is not a constructor
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__angular_cdk_overlay__.OverlayState is 
not a constructor
at MdSnackBar._createOverlay
```

How I can solve that?

Package.json dep versions:

```
"@angular/animations": "4.3.5",
"@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.10",
"@angular/common": "4.3.5",
"@angular/compiler": "4.3.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.5",
"@angular/core": "4.3.5"
```

Comment: Add MdSnackBarModule as root dependency

Comment: Tried, didn't help

Comment: Make sure you are not using MdMaterialModule, because it has been deprecated in material version you have mention

Comment: i'm using `import { MaterialModule, MdRadioModule } from "@angular/material";`

Comment: can you share your code in fiddle or put in the comment

Comment: `this.snackBar.open(value, "Ok", {
            duration: 3000
          });`
its quite strange that error description starts with _WEBPACK_IMPORTED

Comment: If you are using a separate component for snackbar let say CustomSnackBarComp then give this component in entryComponents: [ CustomSnackbarComponent ] or if you are using in same component inject MdSnackBar in constructor constructor(snackbar: MdSnackbar){} then use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155296/discussion-between-v-chjen-and-gaurav-sharma).